# JQuery selecting child of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return the content of a text filed as shown from the code and HTML below upon the click of the submit button, but for some reason result always returns undefined, can someone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong /missing here and how to get the value of the text field? Thanks

```
<div class="col_full">       
    <div class="col_full">
        <label for="textFieldLabel">Label<small>*</small></label>
        <input type="text" id="textFieldLabel" name="textFieldLabel" value="" class="sm-form-control required">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col_full">
    <button class="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="addNewField" name="addNewField" value="submit">Add</button>
</div>
```

Code I tried so far:

```
$('#addNewField').closest('.col_full').children('[name=textFieldLabel]').val();
$('#addNewField').parent().children('[name=textFieldLabel]').val();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse to previous sibling of submit buttons parent div and then find the element in it:

```
$('#addNewField').parent().prev().find('[name=textFieldLabel]').val();
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works now smoothly :) Do you happen to know a good tutorial on manipulating dom elements using JQuery? I tried the JQuery website where I see a lot of functions but couldn't really grab the idea on how to manipulate dom elements there. Thanks

Comment: @MChan: i would suggest you to take the dom and try traversing and manipulation in it. well that is how i learnt. looking at those methods from library wont help much to get trained.

Answer (score 4):

Your input field has id. So you can just use `$("#textFieldLabel").val()`. If there is only one input on the page with the name `textFieldLabel`, you can find the input by its name as well: `$("input[name=textFieldLabel]").val()`.

Comment: `name` doesn't have to be unique like ID does, so ID is more appropriate here

Comment: @RGraham Thanks! I've stated that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#addNewField').parent().prev('.col_full').find('input[name=textFieldLabel]').val();
```

Comment: this will even target the next siblings.